# Remove Chapter number of bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, koma-script, chapters, fancyhdr

I have a little problem with my bibliography. In the toc my Bibliography shows up right (without Chapter number). But in Text it shows the word "chapter" and the chapter number of the previous chapter. But it shouldn't (see screenshots). (I am using overleaf for writing).

```
% ============= Dokumentklasse =============
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

% ============= Packages =============
% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% ============= Zitation =============
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = apa, sortcites = true, alldates=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\setquotestyle[quotes]{german}

% ============= Überschriften =============
\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \reset@font
        \LARGE \scshape \@chapapp{}  \thechapter\vspace*{-15\p@}
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M\hrulefill\newline\vspace*{-5\p@}
        \raggedleft \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vspace*{-8\p@}%
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{4\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape
        \interlinepenalty\@M\hrulefill\newline\vspace*{-5\p@}
        \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vspace*{-8\p@}%
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}

\makeatother
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont\normalcolor\bfseries}





\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{TESTT}

TEXT
\chapter{TEST}
TEXT

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]

\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Example for literature

```
@inbook{Rhomberg.2005,
 author = {Rhomberg, Markus},
 title = {{Wirklich die \glqq vierte Gewalt\grqq?}},
 pages = {123--140},
 bookpagination = {page},
 publisher = {{Springer VS}},
 isbn = {978-3-531-14561-7},
 editor = {Jansen, Stephan A. and Priddat, Birger P.},
 booktitle = {{Korruption}},
 year = {2005},
 abstract = {},
 subtitle = {{Funktionsverstiindnisse fUr die Massenmedien in der Gesellschaft}},
 location = {Wiesbaden},
 booksubtitle = {{Unaufgekl{\"a}rter Kapitalismus --- Multidisziplin{\"a}re Perspektiven zu Funktionen und Folgen der Korruption}}
}


@inbook{Rossler.2013,
 author = {R{\"o}ssler, Patrick and Geise, Stephanie},
 title = {{Standardisierte Inhaltsanalyse: Grundprinzipien, Einsatz und Anwendung}},
 pages = {269--288},
 bookpagination = {page},
 publisher = {{Springer VS}},
 isbn = {978-3-531-18775-4},
 editor = {M{\"o}hring, Wiebke and Schl{\"u}tz, Daniela},
 booktitle = {{Handbuch standardisierte Erhebungsverfahren in der Kommunikationswissenschaft}},
 year = {2013},
 abstract = {},
 location = {Wiesbaden}
}
```

[image: This is right]

[image: Should not show Kapitel and chapter number]

[image: It should look like this]

Comment: I copy-and-pasted your MWE, removed the bits I don't have (your `\include`'d `.tex` files) and replace it with dummy content. When I then run the code (https://gist.github.com/moewew/6fabd4f9aa6a46da397514c63d2a4de5) I get a completely different output. Can you please reduce your example file as much as possible, make sure that it is compilable (test your code in a **new, empty** Overleaf project) and reproduces the output you show. Note that KOMA-Script classes aren't particularly fond of `fancyhdr` `Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.`.

Comment: @moewe I changed my example. I hope it's okay. The problem disappears, when I delete the chapter style. Is there any option to keep the chapter style but fix the problem?

Comment: I'm no KOMA-Script expert, but your redefinition of `\@makechapterhead` destroys the `\addchap` command. I seriously doubt this definition is a good idea. Maybe you want to ask a new question about how to obtain your desired chapter heading format in a KOMA-Script class *without* `fancyhdr` and without this definition of the internal command `\@makechapterhead`.

Comment: It is probably not the best option, but this works for me
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]

Answer (score 1):

With a KOMA-Script class do not redefine internal commands like `\@makechapterhead` or `\@smakechapterhead`.You can redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` instead and use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` for `chapter`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}% not recommended with a KOMA-Script class
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = apa, sortcites = true, alldates=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\setquotestyle[quotes]{german}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {%
      \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\vspace*{6\p@}}
      {\raggedright#2}%
      \interlinepenalty\@M\hrulefill\newline\vspace*{-5\p@}
      #3\par\nobreak
      \vspace*{-8\p@}%
      \hrulefill
      \par\nobreak
    }
    
}
\makeatother
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=4pt,
  afterindent=false,
  innerskip=-15pt,
  afterskip=30pt,
  font=\scshape\Large,
  prefixfont=\mdseries\LARGE
]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont\normalcolor\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{TESTT}
TEXT
\chapter{TEST}
TEXT
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]